# sort by domain giving priority to some domains

Tags: php

I got a list of url's like this:

```
https://www.4shared.com/web/embed/
https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
- https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
https://videoz.me/embed-
https://verystream.com/e/4 
https://ok.ru/videoembed/
- https://ok.ru/videoembed/
https://drive.google.com/file/d/
https://mega.nz/embed#!
- https://mega.nz/embed#!
https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-
```

it's sorted by domain 
but i want sort this by showing ok.ru first if exist and giving number to every url like this

```
1-https://ok.ru/videoembed/
2-https://ok.ru/videoembed/
3-https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-
4-https://mega.nz/embed#!
5-https://mega.nz/embed#!
6-https://www.4shared.com/web/embed/
7-https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
8-https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
9-https://videoz.me/embed-
10-https://verystream.com/e/4 
11-https://drive.google.com/file/d/
```

if ok.ru not exist show mp4upload first like this

```
1-https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-
2-https://mega.nz/embed#!
3-https://mega.nz/embed#!
4-https://www.4shared.com/web/embed/
5-https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
6-https://letsupload.co/plugins/mediaplayer/site
7-https://videoz.me/embed-
8-https://verystream.com/e/4 
9-https://drive.google.com/file/d/
```

```php
$urls = array("https://www.4shared.com/web/embed/","https://drive.google.com/file/d/","https://verystream.com/e/4 ",....);
$urls_categorised = Array();

// First, group all the array elements by HOST
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($url != $host)
        $urls_categorised[$host][] = $url;
}

// Now render each category in the way you specified
foreach ($urls_categorised as $x) {
    if (!count($x))
        continue;

    sort($x);
    print "{$x[0]}\n<br>";
    array_shift($x);

    foreach ($x as $y)
        print "- {$y}\n<br>";
}
```

So can anyone point me in the right direction how to sort this list thank you :)

Comment: What result does the posted code look like? Also, are the urls hard coded like that or do they come from a database or something?

Comment: the code posted result like the first list added in my question and this urls is an array

Comment: If the list is hard coded, why not just put the data in the correct order to begin with?

Comment: i want get the data by showing specific domain in the first position

Comment: In _this particular case_, you can achieve this by simply initializing the array variable you are collecting these elements in, with `$urls_categorised['ok.ru'] = [];` before the loop. By explicitly setting this element before the loop, `$urls_categorised['ok.ru']` is automatically the first item, no matter what order the rest actually comes in.

Comment: @misorude Thank tou very much it's working :D